Fill gaps in one high resolution raster with data from another low resolution raster using QGIS
I have a high res (5m) image with data gaps due to cloud cover. I want to fill these gaps somehow, and have a lower res (30m) raster which has data in these gap areas. I've tried merging in QGIS, but the higher resolution is then lost. Is there a way to composite these rasters to fill the gaps while maintaining the high resolution where that data is available?

I am able to answer my own question here following a bit of playing around...
I found that a solution was to upsample the low resolution raster from 30m to 5m and then merge. This seems to have done the trick.
